# Using complete graphs and a combinatorial proof, show $\sum_{i=1}^{j}$ ${k_i}\choose{2} $ $\leq$ ${n}\choose{2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinatorial-proofs

> Suppose we have a set of positive integers {${k_1, k_2, ... , k_j}$} such that $
> \sum_{i=1}^{j} k_i = n $. Use a combinatorial proof to show $\sum_{i=1}^{j}$ ${k_i}\choose{2} $ $\leq$ ${n}\choose{2}$. Hint: Use complete graphs.

I know complete graphs have ${n}\choose{2}$ total edges as we know each vertex in a complete graph will be connected to $n-1$ total edges, and so to remove the duplicates we divide by 2, as in $n(n-1)/2$ total edges. How can we use this to show that it is greater than the LHS?

Answer (score 1):

The interpretation of the $\{k_1, k_2, \dots, k_j\}$ is a partition of the vertices, so $\binom{k_i}2$ is the number of edges within that partition. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Oh, in that case I am interpreting the question very differently. So is {$k_1, k_2,...,k_j$} referring to a partition of vertices of a complete graph? In which case, the number of edges will always be less in a partition than the number of edges in the entirety of the graph?

Comment: Yep, sounds good!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the graph made of $j$ connected components. The $i^{th}$ component being the complete graph with $k_i$ verticies. Now compare this graph with the connected graph on $n$ verticies.

By considering the number of edges the inequality follows.